# Saving Dictionary with NSAttributed String into a PList or into NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, save, plist, nsuserdefaults, nsattributedstring

I've a Dictionary with an `NSAttributtedString`

```
{
    9 =     {
        9x0 =         {
            UserID = 123;
            formattedMessage = "Hi... How are you ?{\n    CTForegroundColor = \"<CGColor 0x601e460> [<CGColorSpace 0x6010020> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceGray)] ( 0 1 )\";\n    NSFont = \"CTFont <name: Cochin-BoldItalic, size: 17.000000, matrix: 0x0>\\nCTFontDescriptor <attributes: <CFBasicHash 0x6070640 [0x11f8400]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,\\nentries =>\\n\\t1 : <CFString 0xf4d5c4 [0x11f8400]>{contents = \\\"NSFontNameAttribute\\\"} = <CFString 0x60707f0 [0x11f8400]>{contents = \\\"Cochin-BoldItalic\\\"}\\n}\\n>\";\n}";
            isDeleted = 0;
            isEdited = 0;
            lastModifiedDate = "2011-10-19 17:27:38 +0000";
            message = "Hi... How are you ?";
        };
    };
}
```

I tried Saving this Dictionary as a Plist in the Documents folder 
and also, 
save the dictionary in `NSUserDefaults`.
Neither of it worked. 
Both methods work if the attributed string in the dictionary is removed.

Code used to save to Plist in Documents folder :

```
NSString *aDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *aFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ChatHistory.plist",aDocumentsDirectory];
BOOL aStatus = [aDictionary writeToFile:aFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Code used to save Dictionary in `NSUserDefaults` :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:aDictionary forKey:@"ChatHistory"];
```

Someone please help. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An interesting Implementation.
Guess this is a solution :

https://devforums.apple.com/message/340283#340283

will explore this now..